# Why changing a value doesn't change the Scipy Spline value?

Tags: scipy, interpolation, spline

I have the following code trying to interpolate air temperature values

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import RectBivariateSpline as spline

x = np.array([-7.52, -7.50, -7.48, -7.46])
y = np.array([41.88, 41.90, 41.92, 41.94])
z = np.array([
    [1.2, 1.1, 1.5, 1.3],
    [1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.1],
    [1.2, 1.1, 1.2, 1.6],
    [1.3, 1.1, 1.2, 1.5]
    ])
f = spline(x, y, z)
```

When I call the function with `f.ev(41.89, -7.46)` the value remains the same `[ 1.3]` even when I change the values of z. Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Are you creating a new `f` object after changing the values of `z`?  Evidently `f` is using a copy of `z`, not `z` itself.  You need to update the evaluator the see the effects of changing `z`.

I could add a demonstration if needed.

---

```
In [373]: x = np.array([-7.52, -7.50, -7.48, -7.46])
In [374]: y = np.array([41.88, 41.90, 41.92, 41.94])
In [375]: z = np.array([
   .....:     [1.2, 1.1, 1.5, 1.3],
   .....:     [1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.1],
   .....:     [1.2, 1.1, 1.2, 1.6],
   .....:     [1.3, 1.1, 1.2, 1.5]
   .....:     ])
In [376]: f=interpolate.RectBivariateSpline(x,y,z)

In [378]:  f(41.89,-7.46)
Out[378]: array([[ 1.3]])
In [379]:  f.ev(41.89,-7.46)
Out[379]: array(1.3)

In [381]: z+=2
In [382]: z
Out[382]: 
array([[ 3.2,  3.1,  3.5,  3.3],
       [ 3.3,  3.4,  3.5,  3.1],
       [ 3.2,  3.1,  3.2,  3.6],
       [ 3.3,  3.1,  3.2,  3.5]])
In [383]:  f.ev(41.89,-7.46)
Out[383]: array(1.3)
In [384]: f=interpolate.RectBivariateSpline(x,y,z)
In [385]:  f.ev(41.89,-7.46)
Out[385]: array(3.3000000000000003)
```

Comment: Yes. I change the hardcoded values of z, save and run the script again.

Comment: Probably my question is about how spline works and not about the python implementation